Windows 10 PowerShell: allow service interact with desktop (non system user)
The problem is: I have remote desktop, I have set up gitlab runner on it. I am running GUI application (with OpenGL) within my gitlab runner service.
When I am using System User for gitlab runner my GUI application doesn't start at all. But when I switch to my user the application starts, I can see the process in task manager but I can't see any windows of my application popping up.
I tried to write AllowServiceInteraction = 1 parameter in registry configuration of my gitlab runner service, nothing changed.
I tried to run test directly from PowerShell on my remote machine and print out window stations and compare window stations through runner service and PowerShell - they are different.
Is there any way to set window station for runner service?
